# I can't access internet pages when i use xampp localhost

Tags: php, html, macos, xampp

I use xampp on osX for my php files but when I use localhost, I can run php lines correctly but I can't open a page like google with `<a>` tag!
 when I use "localhost/test.php to run my program which is :

```
<html>
<?php echo "<a href='google.com'> google </a>" ?>
</html>
```

when I click on google ... this link opens: localhost/google.com which doesn't exist of course! And I tried using "http://google.com" or "../google.com" but it didn't work ... what should I do?

Comment: need to do some reading on how relative vs absolute paths work. Problem has nothing to do with running localhost....it is how browser interprets those href values

Comment: If I try using "http​:​/​/google.com" in the same setup (a php program running on localhost), it works as expected, so I don't know why that one wouldn't work for you. Or why the answers insist on including the s and the www.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the right adress.

Like `https://www.google.com/` <- with "www"

You could add a tag on the `<a href="...">` which is `target="_blank"`

Complete Example:

`<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>`

[Here](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/Referenz:HTML/Attribute/target) are the possible targets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @saee Remember to accept the answer and feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target=_blank>Google</a>
```

Give it a try